# How to set HTTP Params in Angular without the key?

Tags: angular, parameters, http-parameters

Whenever I try to set HttpParams it's like:

```
let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('someKey', this.key)
```

but my API URL looks like this:

```
/api/something/99999/item
```

So how to set `this.key` like this which is `99999`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you don't need `HttpParams`.

You can directly pass `this.key` to the url like this :

```
const url = `api/something/${this.key}/item`;
```

And after do the http call with the url.

Comment: i know this way, but I would prefer to use HttpParams, if it's possible of course

Comment: It is not possible. If you are using `HttpParams`, it will result a URL with Parameters like `api/heroes/?name=foo` as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the url without the HttpParams

```
this.http.get('/api/something/' + this.key + '/item')
```

Comment: i know this way, but I would prefer to use HttpParams